# use JavaScript to copy and edit rows

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have two textareas and a button that copy the value of textarea 1 to textarea 2  and I need to add "$" in front of every line in the textarea 2 after copy?

Comment: You need to include enough information, including code, for us to reproduce the problem you're having.

Comment: At which point are you having problems?

Comment: What problem are you having?  What part of this process are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are looking for but this should do the trick for the exact situation you are talking about

```
var text = $('#textarea1').text().split('\n').join('\n$');
text = '$'+text;
$('#textarea2').text(text);
```

But not sure what the exact problem is, if you provide more information could give you a better solution

Answer (score 0):

```js
function check(){
 var firstText = $("#first").val();

 $("#second").val("$"+firstText);
}
```

```css
textarea {
margin : 0;
width: 300px;
height: 115px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<textarea rows="5" cols="3" id="first" >Testing By kalyan</textarea>

<textarea rows="5" cols="3" id="second"></textarea>

<input type="submit" id="check" onclick="check()" value="Check">

</body>
```

[more information](http://gudlakalyan.blogspot.in/2015/03/httpstackoverflowcomquestions28593143us.html)